# Sorting & section in UItableview from JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have defined the data model for packages data, but need to define `UITableview` sections on the basis of

> subscriptiontype = 'Yearly', 'Monthly', 'Weekly'

Getting an error of - Cannot assign value of type '`[Package]`' to type '`[[String : String]]`?'. How can I assign it to tableview sections.

**Code:**

```
var packag = [Package]()
enum TableSection: Int {
    case subscriptionType = 0, yearly, monthly, weekly, total
}
var data = [TableSection: [[String: String]]]()

func sortData() {
    data[.yearly] = packag.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "yearly" })
    data[.monthly] = packag.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "monthly" })
    data[.weekly] = packag.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "weekly" })

}
```

**Updated Code - viewdidload():**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self


    //fetchData()
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "packageList", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom{ decoder -> Date in
                let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
                let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
                return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dateStr)!)
            }
            let jSON = try? decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)

            if let packages = jSON?.packages {
                self.sortData(packages: packages)
                print(packages)

            }
        } catch {
            // handle error
            print(Error.self)
        }
    }

}
```

**Root Model:**

```
struct Root : Codable {

    let packages : [Package]
}
```

**Packages Model:**

```
struct Package : Codable {

    let availableUntil : Date
    let benefits : [String]?
    let desc : String
    let didUseBefore : Bool
    let name : String
    let price : Double
    let subscriptionType : String
    let tariff : Tariff
}
```

**Traiff Model:**

```
struct Tariff : Codable {

    let data : String
    let sms : String
    let talk : String
}
```

**Updated PackageJson Data:**

```
{ "packages": [
{
  "name": "Platinum Maksi 6 GB",
  "desc": "Zengin içerikli Platinum Maksi Paketi ile Turkcell Uygulamalarının keyfini sürün!",
  "subscriptionType": "monthly",
  "didUseBefore": true,
  "benefits": [
    "TV+",
    "Fizy",
    "BiP",
    "lifebox",
    "Platinum",
    "Dergilik"
  ],
  "price": 109.90,
  "tariff": {
    "data": "6144",
    "talk": "2000",
    "sms": "100"
  },
  "availableUntil": "1558131150"
},
{
  "name": "Platinum Maksi 8 GB",
  "desc": "Zengin içerikli Platinum Maksi Paketi ile Turkcell Uygulamalarının keyfini sürün!",
  "subscriptionType": "monthly",
  "didUseBefore": false,
  "benefits": [
    "TV+",
    "Fizy",
    "BiP",
    "lifebox",
    "Platinum",
    "Dergilik"
  ],
  "price": 129.90,
  "tariff": {
    "data": "8192",
    "talk": "2000",
    "sms": "100"
  },
  "availableUntil": "1555060350"
},
{
  "name": "Platinum Maksi 12 GB",
  "desc": "Zengin içerikli Platinum Maksi Paketi ile Turkcell Uygulamalarının keyfini sürün!",
  "subscriptionType": "yearly",
  "didUseBefore": false,
  "benefits": [
    "TV+",
    "Fizy",
    "BiP",
    "lifebox",
    "Platinum",
    "Dergilik"
  ],
  "price": 109.90,
  "tariff": {
    "data": "12288",
    "talk": "2000",
    "sms": "100"
  },
  "availableUntil": "1555060350"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a `Package` object to a value that is expecting an array of dictionary.

Your `data` variable is a dictionary that has a `TableSection` as a key, and an array of dictionaries as the value which you have defined by writing `[[String: String]]`. Then in your `sortData` function you're trying to assign a value to various data keys, but you're assigning a `Package` item to it when it's expecting an array of dictionaries.

What will work is if you change your data definition to

```
var data = [TableSection: Package]()
```

Comment: Thank you. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
    import Foundation

    struct JSON: Codable {
        let packages: [Package]
    }

    struct Package: Codable {
        let name, desc, subscriptionType: String
        let didUseBefore: Bool
        let benefits: [String]
        let price: Double
        let tariff: Tariff
        let availableUntil: String
    }

    struct Tariff: Codable {
        let data, talk, sms: String
    }
```

Enum

```
enum TableSection: Int {
    case subscriptionType = 0, yearly, monthly, weekly, total
}
```

Data

```
var data = [TableSection: [Package]]()
```

Parsing

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "document", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let jSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode(JSON.self, from: data)

            if let packages = jSON?.packages {
                self.sortData(packages: packages)
            }
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
    }
```

Sorting

```
private func sortData(packages : [Package]) {
    data[.yearly] = packages.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "yearly" })
    data[.monthly] = packages.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "monthly" })
    data[.weekly] = packages.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "weekly" })

    print("Data is \(data)")
}
```

I use LOCAL JSON, you can use server data.

Comment: Thank you let me apply the changes and let you know. BTW way I am also using local file temp basis.

Comment: Sure. I am here, in case your get any help. Thanks.

Comment: I have implement the code but not displaying. All models are perfect (Root, Package, Traiff).  I have set breakpoint but One parsing function is fetchData and Sort Data giving me this  [Packages.PackagesViewController.TableSection.weekly: [] Packages.PackagesViewController.TableSection.yearly: [], Packages.PackagesViewController.TableSection.monthly: []]

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong even the simple fetchData is not calling. 

`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self
        
        fetchData()
        self.sortData(packages: packag)
        
    }`

Comment: fetchData is local or server api based?

Comment: fetchData is local json file.

Comment: Can I see your parsing code, as I put parsing code also.

Comment: Part One `if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "packageList", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom{ decoder -> Date in
                    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
                    let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
                    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(dateStr)!)
                }`

Comment: Part Two `let jSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                //self.packag = jSON.packages
                //self.sortData(packages: packages)
//
                if let packages = jSON?.packages {
                    self.sortData(packages: packages)
                    print(packages)
                    //tableview.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                // handle error
                print(Error.self)
            }
        }`

Comment: Can you modify your question or share code by online tool, as here in comment, its not worthy.

Comment: I have updated the question and include all data models, packageList json and  `func viewDidLoad()`

Comment: print packages after             if let packages = jSON?.packages {
. see what response comes in.

Comment: Plus keep decoder simple. as I did, No idea why you doing decoder, date etc

Comment: I have print(packages) it gives me PackageList.json parsed data and decoder for date `"availableUntil": "1558131150"  to 2019-05-17 22:12:30`  but  this line gives `print("Data is \(data)")`  empty result --  `Packages.PackagesViewController.TableSection.weekly: []`

Comment: Please check https://www.dropbox.com/s/jr17pqetigb2l0c/SandboxApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: Yes i have checked your project its working fine. Let me share mine. Just if you have a time please highlight what am i doing wrong. Hopefully i will create new project tomorrow. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6o967xkngdfoc5u/Packages.zip?dl=0

Comment: I have found the error now its working. Thank you for such a useful support.

Comment: If my answer really help, please accept & upvote, so others get it a valid answer for such problems.